# JavaScript object property with no value does not show up

Tags: javascript

I tried this out today:

```
var x = new Object();
x.foo;
console.log(x);
console.log(x.length);
```

Result:

`{}`

`undefined`

Why when creating an empty property of an object does the object come up as empty?

Comment: You didn't create a property. You accessed a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: You're not creating the property, you're accessing it' try with x.foo = undefined, then it will show up

Comment: Note that a regular object doesn't have a `length` property. The question clearly shows that you have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not creating the `foo` property; you're *evaluating* the expression `x.foo`, which results in `undefined`, since the property `foo` does not exist. This does not affect the object.

Comment: Good point. On a side note when I give `x.foo` a value like this `x.foo = 'bar'` length still comes up as undefined.

Comment: I was also going to point out that objects do not have a `length` property, either. You can use `Object.keys()`, but if you need something like that, it's best to use a `Map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @RobertRocha why would you expect there to be a `length` property? Plain JS objects are basically a hash/map that holds keys and values. By default they have none of their own and you have to populate them.

Comment: @vlaz i was thinking with a jQuery mindset. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an empty proprety .. you're doing NOTHING literally (unless we're considering trying to access an non-existing property a thing)!

Try:

```
x.foo = undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't created a property, you have tried accessing an non-existing property. If you had tried to assign a value to the property. The property would have been created

```
var x = new Object();
x.foo = undefined;
console.log(x);
console.log(x.length);
```

would print `{foo: undefined}` and `undefined` respectfully

Answer (score 0):

Look these, hope help you

```js
var x = new Object();

x.foo;

console.log('x: ', x);
console.log('x.length', x.length);

var y = new Object();

y['foo'] = '';


console.log('y', y);
console.log('keys:', Object.keys(y));
console.log('keys length:', Object.keys(y).length);
```